# Angular & AngularFire & Firebase - issing or insufficient permissions on singOut

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

Having an issues with current setup. Implemented firebase rules (which where open) and its broken my signOut method. Original ruleset was

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

which doesn't produce an error. However the following production rules does

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

the function that produces this error for firebsae is

```
this.afAuth.auth.signOut()
```

From researching other answers and similar problems I have tried downgrading firebase to 4.6.2 and AngularFire to 5.0.0.rc5-next which fixed others issue but  does not fix mine. Also upgraded to the latest version of both and still same issues.

Also enabled firebase debugging and get the following error

```
Firestore (5.0.4) 2018-07-19T18:38:29.488Z [Connection]: WebChannel received: {"targetChange":{"cause":{"code":7,"message":"Missing or insufficient permissions."},"targetChangeType":"REMOVE","targetIds":[2]}}
```

Other answers also included the following lines before the signOut() method, but still no joy

```
firebase.database().goOffline();
this.db.database.goOffline();
```

At this point I can either implement open firebase rules, or not call this.afAuth.auth.signOut() and given the choice and not that many people will logout of the app and then in as another user, I will probably go that way but just want to ask if there is anything else people can suggest before I do this.

Comment: What do you do after signing out? My guess is that you try to fetch data after logging out the user.

Comment: Aim is to not do anything. auth.signOut is the last line of code, and ive made sure that I have unsubscribed to any observables, have even tried take(1) so that it automatically unsubscribes but got no further. Is there any way to see calls after signout (have also tried debugging but just goes into a minified wormhole :( )

Comment: The official js documentation states that the method returns a promise, so you are able to handle it like `firebase.auth().signOut().then( // do something)`. Not sure about angularfire...

Comment: Just took a look at [angularfire docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md) and it says you can use any of the [firebase auth methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth) so you should be able to do something after using it

Comment: Thanks for replying and having a look. I tried with the returned promise. heres my onSignOut()     t`his.authService.trySilentLogin().then(() => {
      this.authService.signOut().then (() => {
        this.nav.setRoot(LoginPage);
        this.menuCtrl.close();
        this.menuCtrl.swipeEnable(false);
        if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
          this.googlePlus.logout();
        }
      })
    })` with `return this.afAuth.auth.signOut() in the auth service`(No active subscriptions in app.comp or login.ts as well :-(

Comment: And you still got the same error?

Comment: yep still 'missing or insufficient permissions'. Have been working on it all day, still no joy. Plus now if I want to log a user back in automatically if they close the app,  I check for the auth but if a different user logs back in I have to sign them out of firebase otherwise they will get logged back in as another user :(